# Base class for generic classes with different amount of types

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, events

I currently implement a custom event system that can fire a network event additionally to a local one.
It's based on Actions and just like those, it's supposed to take any (up to 16) amount of generic types. (Event, Event<T>, Event<T1, T2>, ...)
My current approach is to hardcode all possible classes (see code example), but this screams for some sort of base class or interface. But due to the different amount of generics, I can't quite figure out how the baseclass/interface should look like.

Do you have an idea? Or is the only way of implementing this how I currently do it?

I would appreciate some help! Thank you!

```
public class Event
{
    private Action eventAction = delegate {  };
    
    public void Subscribe(Action function) => eventAction += function;
    public void Unsubscribe(Action function) => eventAction -= function;
    public void Invoke(bool invokeNetworkEvent = false)
    {
        //invoke local event
        eventAction?.Invoke();

        if (!invokeNetworkEvent) return;
        //invoke network event
    }
}

public class Event<T1>
{
    private Action<T1> eventAction = delegate(T1 _obj1) {  };

    public void Subscribe(Action<T1> function) => eventAction += function;
    public void Unsubscribe(Action<T1> function) => eventAction -= function;
    public void Invoke(T1 _param1, bool invokeNetworkEvent = false)
    {
        //invoke local event
        eventAction?.Invoke(_param1);
        
        if (!invokeNetworkEvent) return;
        //invoke network event
    }
}

public class Event<T1, T2>
{
    private Action<T1, T2> eventAction = delegate(T1 _obj1, T2 _obj2) {  };

    public void Subscribe(Action<T1, T2> function) => eventAction += function;
    public void Unsubscribe(Action<T1, T2> function) => eventAction -= function;
    public void Invoke(T1 _param1, T2 _param2, bool invokeNetworkEvent = false)
    {
        //invoke local event
        eventAction?.Invoke(_param1, _param2);
        
        if (!invokeNetworkEvent) return;
        //invoke network event
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is a `network event`?

Comment: It basically serializes the Action and the parameters into strings and sends those over the network. The concrete implementation should not matter for this question.

Comment: You can't serialize code. Unless you meant just the name of a method.

Comment: Of course you can't serialize code. By "serializing the Action" I mean that it gets the event's name by reflection to send it (together with the serialized parameters) over a network in order to have a client call the same action on their machine. But as stated before this isn't relevant for my question.